# How can I get offset of td using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, offset

I have a simple table:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

and I need to get offset of cell on which cursor is hovered on jQuery

Comment: Create a `mouseover` event and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkotbxrp/3/)

#### HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('td').mouseover(function() {
    var ofst = $(this).offset();
    $('div').html('(' + ofst.top + ', ' + ofst.left + ')');
});
```